# JS IF Else And syntax

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax

Have looked on google and w3schools, but can't find an solution to my question.

If I have two values A and B, how will the JS IF syntax then look like if:

- Do condition if Only A is filled
- Do condition if Only B is filled
- Do condition if both A AND B is filled
- Else do condition if non are filled

Comment: what is "*filled*" do you have an html element input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with the most specific first since the logic starts from the top to the bottom of the list. In this case you would need to check for both A and B to start, followed by the other checks which do not depend on multiple conditions.

```
if (A && B) {}
else if (A || B) {}
else {}
```

if you need to know difference between A and B

```
if (A && B) {}
else if (A) {}
else if (B) {}
else {}
```

Comment: THX alot, don't why the -1 to the question, but nice solution and helped med alot.
Thx epascarello

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the OR operator:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

Answer (score 0):

Considering that by filled you mean the variable which is not filled would be empty, below are the IF conditions in JS that should fit each of your conditions.

**Do condition if Only A is filled**

```
if(A!="" && B==""){
    // do something if only A is filled
}
```

**Do condition if Only B is filled**

```
if(A=="" && B!=""){
    // do something if only B is filled
}
```

**Do condition if both A AND B are filled. Else do condition if non are filled**

```
if(A!="" && B!=""){
    // do something if A and B are filled
}else{
    // do something if A and B are not filled
}
```